# how to split a column by another column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, data-cleaning

I am cleaning data in pandas dataframe, I want split a column by another column.

I want split column 'id' by column 'eNBID',but don't know how to split

```py
import pandas as pd

id_list = ['4600375067649','4600375077246','460037495681','460037495694']
eNBID_list = ['750676','750772','749568','749569']
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':id_list,'eNBID':eNBID_list})

df.head()

id                  eNBID
4600375067649       750676
4600375077246       750772
460037495681        749568
460037495694        749569

What I want:

df.head()

id                     eNBID
460-03-750676-49       750676
460-03-750772-46       750772
460-03-749568-1        749568
460-03-749569-4        749569

#column 'eNBID' is the third part of column 'id', the item length in column 'eNBID' is 6 or 7.
```

Comment: Did you try `df.iterrows()` ?

Comment: I try ```df.id.str.map(lambda x:x.split(df.eNBID.str))```  it can't work

Answer (score 1):

considering the `46003` will remain same for all ids

```
df['id'] = df.apply(lambda x: '-'.join([i[:3]+'-'+i[3:] if '460' in i else i for i in list(re.findall('(\w*)'+'('+x.eNBID+')'+'(\w*)',x.id)[0])]), axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
                 id   eNBID
0  460-03-750676-49  750676
1  460-03-750772-46  750772
2   460-03-749568-1  749568
3   460-03-749569-4  749569
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering '-' after 3rd, 5th, 11th position:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].apply(lambda s: s[:3] + '-' + s[3:5] + '-' + s[5:11] + '-' + s[11:])
```